# More elegant way to define a flexible application configuration in spring boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, application.properties

I want a spring boot app that has a flexibility to use the default embedded configuration files; but also has a flexibility to be able to override it with an external configuration files.

During debugging, I wish it to uses the embedded property file inside the jar file. But during deployment, I want it to use the external application.yml so I can customize values on production.

I tried a lot of forum but there seems to be no other way out of this. Does this give priority to the embedded one and overwrite it

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.yml"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:application.yml", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

I manually moved the yml to be in target directory.

```
<!-- Copy the config to target -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.resource.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>*.yml</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above seems able to work. But I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to do this. I have my doubts since the property source array did not seem to specify the priority, it may just work for now. Do we have another way to do this aside from how I did it?

Comment: IMHO, you misuse `@PropertySource`. What you want is solved using spring profiles

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I am actually using the spring profiles too. I just want ease of debugging and flexibility of customization. While debugging, I use the one I comitted, but I have flexibility on production.

Comment: On production just start application with different profile. You also can combine - have part of prod properties committed to VCS (e.g. thread counts, timeouts etc) and part of prod properties placed on target box (credentials etc) and combine these on fly

Comment: Thank you for silently removing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62383390/how-to-override-the-primefaces-widget after us commenting. That is a good incentive to help on further questions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Spring has profiles for this.
Spring boot can read from `src/main/resources/application.properties` (and config folder works as well) by default, however if you put property like this:

```
--spring.profiles.active=dev
```

It will also read stuff from `/src/main/resources/application-dev.properties` (suffix must match the profile). Yaml works like this as well.

So, this should cover the "development" mode.

Now, in a real environment you can activate some other profile + use another option that spring boot offers for free: `--spring.config.locations=...`. This one allows specifying an external source of configuration.

So, you don't need to copy resources, fiddle with property source and so forth, instead, you can rely on spring boot regular mechanisms of configurations.

All-in-all you can read the [relevant chapter in documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) but this should cover a deployment case.

Last but not least, there are precedences here, so some configuration ways can override the others (I mean if there is a clash between property values with the same name).